# Can you explain this recursive "n choose k" code to me?

Tags: python, recursion

Here is the code to a subset problem with arguments n and k. n represents the total number of students and k represents the amount of the students I want to get out of n. The code attempts to give the number of possible combinations of pulling k number of students out of n number of students.

```
def subset(n, k): 
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    if n == k:
        return 1
    else:
        return subset(n-1, k-1) + subset(n-1, k)
```

I understand the first part of the recursive call, but I'm having trouble understanding the + subset(n-1, k) part. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The recursion is based on a simple observation, for which I will give a combinatorial argument, as to why it is true, rather than a mathematical proof through formulae.

Whenever you choose `k` elements out of `n`, there are two cases:

1. You choose element `#n`
2. You don't choose element `#n`

Since these events are mutually exclusive, the total amount of combinations is given by the amount of combinations when choosing `#n`, and those when you don't choose `#n`.

### Choosing element `#n`

Since we have already chosen one element, we need only choose another `k-1` elements. Also, since we have decided upon one element – as to whether it is included or not – already, we only need to consider the remaining `n-1` elements.

Thus, the amount of combinations for choosing element `#n` is given by

```
    subset(n - 1, k - 1)
```

### Not choosing element `#n`

There are still `k` elements to choose, but since we have already made up our mind about element `#n`, there remain only `n - 1` elements to choose from. Thus:

```
    subset(n - 1, k)
```

### The base case

The recursion uses the fact, that we can usually differentiate between two situations, solutions where element `n` is part of that solution, and those where it is not.

However, such a distinction can not always be made:

- When choosing all elements (corresponding to case `n == k` in code below)
- or when choosing no elements at all (corresponding to case `k == 0` in code below)

In these cases, there is only exactly one solution, hence

```
if k == 0:
    return 1
if n == k:
    return 1
```

### Ensuring it works

To do that, we need to convince ourselves (or prove) that the base case is always hit at some point.

Let us assume, that `n < k` at some point. Since per our assumption, `n` was originally greater or equal to `k`, there *must* have been some point where `n = k`, because `n` and `k` decrease in unison or only `n` decreases by one, i.e. it follows

This implies, that there must have been a call to `subset(n - 1, k)` for it to happen, that `n` decreases below `k`. However, this is not possible since we have a base case on `n = k` where we return a constant `1`.

We conclude that either `n` decreases at some point such that `n = k`, or decrease in unison exactly `k` times such that `k = 0`.

Thus, the base case works.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a mathematical problem and not a programming question. What you are doing is calculating the Binomial coefficient, the formula is

```
(n, k) = (n-1, k-1) + (n-1, k) with all (n, 0) and (n, n) having a value of 1.
```

Please see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) for a full explanation. A recursive solution can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula). In case the mentioned link goes invalid simply search for it using Google. I doubt you will get a better explanation on SO than after reading this article on Wikipedia.

Comment: I'm really just confused about the recursion though.

Answer (score 1):

The code fragment:

```
if k == 0:
    return 1
if n == k:
    return 1
```

uses two combinatorial facts:

```
nC0 = 1
nCn = 1
```

as base cases.

Next, following recursive call:

```
return subset(n-1, k-1) + subset(n-1, k)
```

directly translates the following fact into the code:

```
nCr = (n-1)C(k-1) + (n-1)Ck
```

If you have difficulty in understanding how above equation holds, then read on:
In nCr, we choose r items out of n. The choices can be classified into two mutually exclusive classes if we consider any particular item:

- **item occurs among r chosen item**

  In this case we have to choose remaining r-1 items out of remaining n-1 items. This can be done in (n-1)C(k-1).
- **item does not occur among  r chosen item**

  In this case we have to choose all r items from remaining n-1 items which can be done in (n-1)Ck ways.

We add these two up as I already said these two classes are mutually exclusive and hence together forms the total ways of choosing r items out of n.